# "A second operation started on this context" EF core 3.1 concurrency breaking change

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating from netcoreapp 2.1 to 3.1, and I've found a breaking change for EF core 3.1 that I can't resolve.

Previously in 2.1, this worked:

```
taskList.Add(MethodOne(myRequestObject));
taskList.Add(MethodTwo(myRequestObject));

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

where both methods only read(never changed) from the db context and look something like this:

```
private async Task MethodOne(RequestObject myRequestObject)
{
    var entity = await DbContext
    .MyDbSet
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeProperty)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == myRequestObject.Id);

    if (entity != null)
        myRequestObject.SomeRequestProperty = entity.AnotherProperty;
    }
}
```

In 3.1, even when I'm just reading and not changing the entities, the DB context ConcurrencyDetector thinks it has `EnterCriticalSection` which causes an exception when the second method tries to await on the DbContext:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
>   before a previous operation completed

So, to work around this I replaced `await Task.WhenAll(taskList)` with the following:

```
foreach (var task in taskList)
{
    await task;
}
```

However, this does not work. The same error occurs, as if the second method begins execution without waiting for the first.

For baseline sanity, I also tried the following which **does work**(but is not an ideal solution for the real code of my app):

```
await MethodOne(myRequestObject);
await MethodTwo(myRequestObject);
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to continue to tell EF core 3.1 to allow concurrency when I know it is safe.
2. If not, why the heck is my foreach workaround not working?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Because calling the method *starts* the task. The `await` waits for it to complete. The DbContext and DbSets are *not* thread safe. This is by design, not a bug. It has been this way ever since inception.

Comment: Ya, I am apparently too tired to realize that I was evaluating the methods, thus starting them. I fixed that by using a list of Funcs.

Comment: I just want to clarify that the error isn't exactly due to `DbContext` not being thread safe, as awaiting a task doesn't rely on multi-threading.  The problem is multiple concurrently open reads, which can happen on a single thread as in above code.

Comment: It's "by design" - see the **Warning** in the EF Core docs for [Asynchronous Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async). The fact that it "worked" before is irrelevant. Even though your code is just reading, there are still  many other shared things like change tracker, connection open/close etc. which are not thread-safe.